# How do I determine the ASP.NET version of a virtual directory or website using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, directoryservices

How do I find out the .NET framework of an IIS virtual directory is using in C#.  I need to display it to the user.

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.IO;

private enum IISVersion
{
    IIS5,
    IIS6
}

private void ReadVirtualDirectory(string server, string directory, IISVersion version)
{
    string siteID = string.Empty;
    string path = string.Empty;

    switch(verison)
    {
        case IISVersion.IIS5:
            path = string.Format("IIS://{0}/W3SVC/1/Root", server);

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directory))
            {
                path = string.Concat(path, "/", directory);
            }

            break;

        case IISVersion.IIS6:
            path = string.Format("IIS://{0}/W3SVC", server);

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directory))
            {
                DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(path);

                foreach(DirectoryEntry child in de.Children)
                {
                    if(child.Properties["ServerComment"].Value.ToString().ToLower() == directory)
                    {
                        siteID = child.Name;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                path = string.Concat(path, "/", siteID);

                de.Close()
                de = null;
            }

            break;
    }

    DirectoryEntry iis = new DirectoryEntry(path);

    //display iis properties here...
    //need to display if the virtual directory is running under .NET 1.1 or 2.0

    iis.Close();
    iis = null;       
}
```

Comment: Nice code. What does it do right? What does it do wrong? Doesn't it answer the question you asked? If not, why not?

Comment: you want to know what .NET framework or what version of IIS?

Comment: I want to know the .NET framework.

Comment: @Kev - No need to rollback.  That is a better title for my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In IIS there's no hard and fast way to find out which ASP.NET version is used by a website or 'virtual' directory (website application folder - the one that has cogs as an icon).

The reason for this is that IIS and the metabase data only know about scriptmaps and not ASP.NET versions (after all ASP.NET is just another ISAPI application). One way to determine the version of ASP.NET is to use something like the following:

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/1/root/MyApp";
            Console.WriteLine(GetAspNetVersion(path));
        }

        private static string GetAspNetVersion(string path)
        {
            using (DirectoryEntry app = new DirectoryEntry(path))
            {
                PropertyValueCollection pvc = app.Properties["ScriptMaps"];

                foreach (string scriptMap in pvc)
                {
                    if (scriptMap.StartsWith(".aspx"))
                    {
                        string[] mapping = scriptMap.Split(',');
                        string scriptProcessor = mapping[1];

                        // The version numbers come from the path
                        // C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\
                        // which will be present in the script processor 
                        // DLL path
                        if (scriptProcessor.Contains("v1.1.4322"))
                        {
                            return "1.1";
                        }

                        if (scriptProcessor.Contains("v2.0.50727"))
                        {
                            return "2.0";
                        }
                    }
                }
                throw new Exception("Unknown version ASP.NET version.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not ideal but hasn't failed our needs as a hoster for our provisioning applications/services. I suspect the IIS MMC plug-in performs a similar check behind the scenes. My own detailed examination of the metabase (Windows 2000 and Windows 2003 file based XML) reveals that there isn't a conspicuous property/attribute that stores a specific ASP.NET version number.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I will have to modified it to get the framework version for each virtual directory in the web site.

Answer (score 5):

It might not be the prettiest method, but if you can grab and parse the output from **aspnet_regiis.exe -lk**, you'll get all the information you need.  An example of the output from a SharePoint VHD:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_Regiis -lk
W3SVC/  1.1.4322.2407
W3SVC/1/ROOT/Reports/   2.0.50727.0
W3SVC/1/ROOT/ReportServer/      2.0.50727.0
W3SVC/1619303638/Root/  2.0.50727.0
W3SVC/1619303638/Root/_layouts/images/  1.1.4322.2407
W3SVC/1619303638/Root/_layouts/inc/     1.1.4322.2407
W3SVC/1720207907/root/  2.0.50727.0
W3SVC/1720207907/root/SharedServices1/  2.0.50727.0
W3SVC/1848312571/Root/  2.0.50727.0
W3SVC/1848312571/Root/_layouts/images/  1.1.4322.2407
W3SVC/1848312571/Root/_layouts/inc/     1.1.4322.2407
W3SVC/784543535/Root/   2.0.50727.0
W3SVC/784543535/Root/_layouts/images/   1.1.4322.2407
W3SVC/784543535/Root/_layouts/inc/      1.1.4322.2407
W3SVC/98413328/Root/    2.0.50727.0
W3SVC/98413328/Root/_layouts/images/    1.1.4322.2407
W3SVC/98413328/Root/_layouts/inc/       1.1.4322.2407
```